# Multi instances COM object

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop

I use a C++ written COM object in C#. I just create instance through "new". I need numerous of such objects. But every other "new" doesn't create new instance, but only gives reference on first object. Thats why I have a mess with data. Is it possible to get new instance every time? Or I should realize IClassFactory in my COM to instantiate not singleton?
I've made COM with master in VC 2010 with ATL support. And I have a trouble where and how to realize IClassFactory.

Comment: Getting new unique objects is the default behavior when you don't do anything special with the class factory.  Your C++ is broken somehow, hard to guess what you did wrong from just the "it doesn't work right" question.

Comment: I've made COM from old C++ dll. There's a global object which data are always changed by calling methods of different instances of COM. Is it possible the instances of COM share that global object?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement [IUnknown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [IClassFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Depending on what you're doing you may want to implement [IDispatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [IErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as well. It's quite involved so I won't go into the details here. The following three articles should cover pretty much everything that you are after:

1. [Step by Step COM Tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/tutorials/article.php/c5567/)
2. [Understanding Classic COM Interoperability With .NET
   Applications](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990/Understanding-Classic-COM-Interoperability-With-NE)
3. [Fundamentals of ATL COM Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c43h4867.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I have one more adjustment. I've made COM from old C++ dll. There's a global object which data are always changed by calling methods of different instances of COM. Is it possible the instances of COM share that global object?

Comment: @plax You should make this comment a separate question but, off the top of my head, you may want to look at using shared memory for this. See Creating Named Shared Memory 
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx