# csharp com visible dll understanding

Tags: c#, com

Never worked with COM (prefer TCP socket or WCF) but I have a customer who insist on it.

I have a .net application and I have created the following class from searching here in it for testing purpose:

```
namespace Test112
{

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    [Guid("BBBBBBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBB-BBBBBBBBBBBB")]
    public interface MyCOMInterface
    {
        int assigntest();
        int testreturn();
    }
    [ProgId("Test112.Class1")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAAAAAAAA")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class Class1 : MyCOMInterface
    {

        public int assigntest()
        {
            Class2.number = 25;
            return 0;
        }

        public int testreturn()
        {
            return Class2.number;
        }
    }
}
```

class2:

```
namespace Test112
{
    public class Class2
    {
        public static int number = 70;
    }
}
```

external application should assign a value (25) and another class should read the value of the static field on Class2.

when i use:

```
 Type testlib = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Test112.Class1");
            dynamic comObj = Activator.CreateInstance(testlib);
            var k = comObj.assigntest();
```

it assigned it but when I try to read it from another directly or by using :

```
Type testlib = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Test112.Class1");
            dynamic comObj = Activator.CreateInstance(testlib);
            var k = comObj.testreturn();
```

I keep getting 70 as the value. What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: COM's purpose is very different than TCP or WCF.

Comment: What happens between the last two code snippets? If you call `comObj.testreturn()` immediately after `comObj.assigntest()`, you probably get the correct result. There are many things you could potentially be doing between the last two code snippets -- terminating one program and running another, something to do with AppDomains, etc, etc. If you run the whole second code snippet immediately after the first (use different variables to reduce any GC issues), what is the result?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have created the COM class that returns you different instances whenever you query the interface each and every time from different locations. You can make it as a singleton.  Hope this ([Multi instances COM object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332204/multi-instances-com-object)) will help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

After understanding that i need to create COM server and that both apps needs to register for its events for the purpose of communication between two apps We have decided to move to Named Pipes or Shared Memory. Much easier.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on the likely problem, static data in C# is isolated by Application Pool. I am guessing that you were running these code snippets in different processes or COM servers or something.  In which case each "instance" of `Class2` has its own value for `number`, and setting the value in one AppPool is setting it *in that AppPool only*, and changes are not reflected in other AppPools.

You *might* be able to solve it by using COM+ or other server-side mechanisms, but if you were able to solve it by other means then go with it.